# PowerShell PSCustomObject content editing

Tags: powershell, csv, pscustomobject

I import a CSV file successfully and want to change one value in the PSObject array `$ds`.

```
$ds = Import-Csv test.csv -UseCulture
#test.csv content
#A;B
#11;22
#33;44
$ds
$ds.B[1] = 9
$ds
```

This does not work and nothing else either.
This should be very easy I guess.
But how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to access the correct element in the array. The array here is `$ds` as it contains one object per row. Each row has a `B`-property that you can read and set. This will work:

```
#Modify second row's B-value (44) to 9
$ds[1].B = 9
```

What might confuse you is that `$ds.b[1]` actually returns `44` while using PowerShell 3.0 or later. This is because of a feature called member enumeration, where `$ds.B` will return the `B`-value for every object in the array and then `[1]` selects the second value which is `44`. What's important to know is that member enumeration returns a **read-only** collection by design, so you can't modify the values that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that doesn't work.

This does work, however:

```
$ds = import-csv test.csv -UseCulture
#test.csv content
#A;B
#11;22
#33;44
$ds
$ds[1].B = 9
$ds
```

Comment: You uses different culture settings

Comment: @mazzy Huh? He's using a different technique to access the value which is why it work.. His culture settings doesn't impact his answer.

Comment: Should mention that I meant by "I don't know why that doesn't work" I meant I don't know why accessing the row then the value does work but access the column then the value doesn't. @FrodeF. answer fills that in though :)